# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. I have run some modules today and suddenly have got this message

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried File -> Invalidate caches\Restart, that didn't help me.

Log:

16:05   Gradle sync started
16:05   Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (34s 987ms)

**build.gradle application**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.startandroid.androidlessons"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, any project creates by Android Studio has two separated build.gradle files. That shouldn't cause any problems, for Gradle itself, but Android Studio might not be expecting that.

It's probably a sign that you're continuing to use the new SDK and features, but neglecting to upgrade your build tools along with it. E.g `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2`

You should upgrade that Gradle plugin to the latest version

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

And upgrade Gradle itself, via the Gradle wrapper or install it externally to Android Studio

Comment: When I add                                                                                        
                      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'                             in my  build.gradle file, I get message 'Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.'

Comment: Try reading the link again about upgrading Gradle to version 4.1 or greater, and adding `google()` to the repository section

Comment: I  pressed 'sync Gradle' and that helped.   this line of code with gradle 4.1.-all.zip was in the file  gradle-wrapper.properties.

Answer (score 0):

your build.graddle in project level should look like below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
} 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl should be like:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I replaced my build.gradle and I got this message:  
Cannot invoke method allprojects() on null object

Comment: in your settings graddle did you include application module
include ':app'
also can you remove buildscript and allprojects from your module build.graddle